# Добавления процентов к числу

Tags: php

Например у нас есть число 107, занесем его в переменную

```
$namber = "107";
```

Также у нас есть процент 8% занесем его в переменную

```
$proc = "8";
```

Как достать эти 8 процентов с 107, и потом их добавить к `$nubmer`, и если число получается вот таким 1012.5643, то округлить его к большему, вот так 113?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же математика.

107 / 100 * 8 - это 8%
прибавляешь этот результат к 107 - это 108%
округлить можно функцией round

```
$result = $number/100*$proc;
$result = $result + $proc;
round ($result);
echo $result;
```

Comment: не люблю математику =)

Answer (score 1):

Или я что то не так понял, или в ответе butteff есть ошибочка.
У меня код заработал так:

```
$proc = 10; // количество процентов
$number = 100; // число к которому надо добавить проценты
$proc = $number/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
$result = $number + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
round ($result); // округляем
echo $result; // выводим результат
```

в примере от butteff получается, что мы складываем количество процентов и процент от числа